# Mailchimp API 3.0 fetch all merge-fields including E-Mail

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am currently building a little PHP script that fetches the merge-fields for a list and then automatically builds a small subscription form for that list.

However I am having problems since the only API call I was able to find was: 
`3.0/lists/{list_id}/merge-fields` ([documentation link here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/merge-fields/lists-merge-fields-collection))

This properly returns all the fields that are user defined but it omits the email field which is created by default. However I need to fetch the email field as well in order to check the label, as well as the position within the form. Is there an easy way to do that?

I have also tried to use
`3.0/lists/{list_id}/merge-fields/0` (since the email field got the merge_id '0') which unfortunately does not work either. If I replace the zero with another number then the proper merge-field is returned.

Any ideas if there is a way to retrieve the E-Mail field at all?
Any hints are welcome! :)

Comment: The EMAIL field isn't a real merge field, so it won't come back there. I don't think there's any way to get the field label out of the API right now.

Comment: After talking to one of the API developers it seems that there is currently no way to do this in version 3.0. However it works fine in API version 2.0 and will , accoridng to the developer, probably be added to 3.0 in the future, to make it behave like the earlier release.